# Creating a non-resizeable table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, resize

I currently use the following CSS:

```
table {
  border: 0px solid black;
}
th, td {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
```

Currently, if the content of the cells do not take up all the 36px, when the browser window width does not allow to visualize the entire table, the column width is reduced.

I would like to modify this CSS so that, regardless of the text content of the cells, and regardless of the browser window size, the cells always are 36*36px and the table has a fixed size basically only depending on the number of rows and columns.

How to achieve this?

In the following example, if I resize my browser window, the table size (more exactly the column width) is affected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <style>
      table {
        border: 0px solid black;
      }
      th, td {
        font-family: monospace;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>00</th>
        <th>01</th>
        <th>02</th>
        <th>03</th>
        <th>04</th>
        <th>05</th>
        <th>06</th>
        <th>07</th>
        <th>08</th>
        <th>09</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>21</th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th>23</th>
        <th>24</th>
        <th>25</th>
        <th>26</th>
        <th>27</th>
        <th>28</th>
        <th>29</th>
        <th>30</th>
        <th>31</th>
        <th>32</th>
        <th>33</th>
        <th>34</th>
        <th>35</th>
        <th>36</th>
        <th>37</th>
        <th>38</th>
        <th>39</th>
        <th>40</th>
        <th>41</th>
        <th>42</th>
        <th>43</th>
        <th>44</th>
        <th>45</th>
        <th>46</th>
        <th>47</th>
        <th>48</th>
        <th>49</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MrLister I tried `table-layout: fixed;` for the table and it does not seem to help

Comment: In that case, can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @MrLister Added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the table a fixed width too. And I added some more values for properties, so that we know how wide a cell is instead of guessing at the default values.

```css
table {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width:2002px; /* = (# of columns)*(width of td + borders + border spacing) */
  table-layout:fixed; /* to avoid column widening by too wide content */
  border-spacing:2px; /* because we don't want to rely on defaults */
}

th, td {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding:0; /* because we don't want to rely on defaults */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>01</th>
    <th>02</th>
    <th>03</th>
    <th>04</th>
    <th>05</th>
    <th>06</th>
    <th>07</th>
    <th>08</th>
    <th>09</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
    <th>13</th>
    <th>14</th>
    <th>15</th>
    <th>16</th>
    <th>17</th>
    <th>18</th>
    <th>19</th>
    <th>20</th>
    <th>21</th>
    <th>22</th>
    <th>23</th>
    <th>24</th>
    <th>25</th>
    <th>26</th>
    <th>27</th>
    <th>28</th>
    <th>29</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>31</th>
    <th>32</th>
    <th>33</th>
    <th>34</th>
    <th>35</th>
    <th>36</th>
    <th>37</th>
    <th>38</th>
    <th>39</th>
    <th>40</th>
    <th>41</th>
    <th>42</th>
    <th>43</th>
    <th>44</th>
    <th>45</th>
    <th>46</th>
    <th>47</th>
    <th>48</th>
    <th>49</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```